# Is MemoryMappedFile better option for creating database system?

Tags: .net-4.5, memory-mapped-files

I am trying to create NoSQL kind of database for storing blobs. Each blob will be of fixed size for example 4KB to 64KB. Each blob will be rewritten entirely, so Let's say I have 1GB to 1TB of file, in FileStream I could do Seek and write etc. However I am little skeptical about Locking.

Is MemoryMappedFile for such large file with View of only 4KB to 64KB will perform better? Or should I use FileStream with locking.

FilStream provides Lock API, however MemoryMappedFile does not provide locking, so I will have to use some inter process locking.

My requirements are,

1. I want file to be open only by single process
2. Single process will have multiple threads accessing same MMF but probably different Views
3. I want to easily read/write chunks of 4B to 64KB but with full locking, will use mutex
4. I will be writing entire page of 4KB to 64KB of fixed size and I want to perform Flush only at the end of my processing. But I want this write operation to be extremely durable.

From documentation on MSDN, I see MemoryMappedFile as best candidate to create database system, however I have seen some open source nosql c# databases and I haven't seen any of them use this so it creates doubt that what are bottlenecks. Another reason could be MMF was introduced very late in .NET and those databases did not have option of MMF.

Answer (score 2):

No, pretty unlikely to get mileage out of an MMF for a dbase engine.  For starters, the operating system already provides a memory-mapped view of the file data.  You get it for free from the file system cache.

Using an MMF for reading cannot improve on that.  You want to optimize for the common access patterns, the ones that *should* be fast because the query accesses data sequentially.  Very well supported by the file system cache, it reads ahead to slurp data off the same cylinder on the disk since you get that practically for free.  An MMF is liable to die the Chinese torture death by a thousand pin pricks from the page faults that are triggered when you access the view.  Not an issue when you access the data repeatedly, but that's one thing a dbase engine doesn't do.

An MMF is very nice for writing, you simply write to memory and the operating system lazily updates the file.  But that's the one feature you'd never want to use in a dbase engine, you want to be sure that the file data is updated on disk when the transaction is committed.  You can force a flush but that's crude, the entire view is flushed, not just the data that should be committed.

Comment: Thanks, but how to do multithreaded access to same file? Is it good to have instance of file stream for each thread? Can you suggest how to read/write from multiple thread for same file?

Comment: That's a very different question.  I'm just going to answer the one that was asked.

Comment: It turns out that though you have provided good details, but MMF for database engine is good candidate as only partial memory views help multithread access and needs only one file handle, multiple views can be easily managed by different threads, the only problem is the IO error.